# Finding support resistance levels in a stock price data array with NumPy using Python efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

**I am trying to create a trading bot**

To help the trading bot identify price pattens **I am trying to create a function that is able to find support and resistance levels in a stock price data array without using any 3rd party libraries.**

I don't know if there is any library created to find support and resistance levels.

**I am using Numpy to deal with array data and I am new to Numpy.**

I came up with two different functions for finding support levels.

First one

```
def support_levels(lowest_prices: np.ndarray):
    mask = (lowest_prices[1:-1] < lowest_prices[:-2]) & (lowest_prices[1:-1] < lowest_prices[2:])
    support_levels = lowest_prices[1:-1][mask]
    print(support_levels)
```

**For testing I am not using pandas to read a real stock price data from a .csv file.** Instead I am using a list with random data

```
lowest_prices = np.array([7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 7, 6, 5, 8, 6, 5, 3, 2, 3])
```

When run the first function with the given input I get the output what I wanted but there is error in the output data

```
support_levels(lowest_prices=lowest_prices)
# Output [1 3 5 2]
```

**Error is when 3 and 5 support levels should be deleted when there is support level at 2. Because 2 has broken 3 and 5 support level.**

To fix that I come with this function

```
def support_levels(lowest_prices: np.ndarray):

    support_levels_filter = np.zeros_like(lowest_prices)

    for price_index in range(0, lowest_prices.size):
        if support_levels_filter[price_index - 1] >= lowest_prices[price_index]:

           # Updating value with 0 which are greater than current lowest_prices[price_index]              
           mask = (support_levels_filter >= lowest_prices[price_index]) & (
            support_levels_filter != 0)
           support_levels_filter[mask] = 0

        support_levels_filter[price_index] = lowest_prices[price_index]

    # Removes all 0 values from the support_levels_filter array
    support_levels_filter = support_levels_filter[np.where(support_levels_filter != 0)]
    print(support_levels_filter)

support_levels(lowest_prices=lowest_prices)
# Output [1 2 3]
```

The above function works for me. But It takes lot of time to complete with big arrays.

**I there a efficient way to do what I am doing or is my algorithm wrong. Please correct me**